# Error fetch when App is put in background

Tags: react-native, fetch

I’m running into an issue with my RN app and was wondering if anyone had come across this and how they solved it.
During a fetch call, if the user puts the app in the background and comes back, the fetch always errors out (catch block). Let me know if you have any more questions around this issue.

Comment: Does it give a specific error in your catch block? Any other information you can provide around what you are doing, what is happening, and what you expect to happen will help in troubleshooting whats going on, or getting a solid fix for you.

Comment: @DougWatkins the catch block error returns 'Network request failed'. I would expect it to finish the fetch call and all remaining logic. does that help?

Comment: That can't be guaranteed based on the way backgrounding apps works on mobile. You will have to handle the case where the app is paused when put into the background. For android if you need to do background network requests that don't depend on the app being in the foreground you could consider using headless js: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/headless-js-android

Comment: My thoughts are you can do one of two things. 1 - look into a native solution, that keeps your network open even in the background, this may be simple or complex and since I havent done this I dont have any suggestions on where to start. 2 - If you get that error in your catch block, attempt the call again and propagate the error if the second call fails.

Answer (score 0):

Recently fell into this issue. Sometimes network request fails on iOS when app is in background. https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/106838

You can try below hook which waits for your app to come in foreground before sending requests.

```
import { useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import { AppState, AppStateStatus } from "react-native";

export const useFetchOnAppForeground = () => {
  const listener = useRef(null);

  function fetchOnAppForeground(params) {
    if (AppState.currentState === "active") {
      return fetch(params);
    } else {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        function fetchData(state: AppStateStatus) {
          if (state === "active") {
            console.log("calling foreground fetch");
            fetch(params).then(resolve).catch(reject);
            AppState.removeEventListener("change", fetchData);
            listener.current = null;
          }
        }

        AppState.addEventListener("change", fetchData);
        listener.current = fetchData;
      });
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
      if (listener.current) {
        AppState.removeEventListener("change", listener.current);
      }
    };
  }, []);

  return fetchOnAppForeground;
};
```

```
// Usage
const fetch = useFetchOnAppForeground();
```

Gist - https://gist.github.com/intergalacticspacehighway/e1ec053064871f98f50646f80f99c888

Comment: How to resume the fetch process if it's initiated before app pushed to bg? ie: user submit request and switch to other app, then return to app.