# React Native fetch does not complete if app not in foreground

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo, fetch-api

On my React Native Expo app running on a physical iOS device, clicking a button on the screen runs a `fetch` command that uses the JS Fetch API to send a GET request to a API URL that returns a JSON response which is used to set a state using the `useState` hook `set` function.

While testing my app, I notice that if the app was to be moved to the background before the `fetch` completes, then the `fetch` will fail with the error

> TypeError: Network request failed

even though the server logs show that the request had returned a 200.

Seems like iOS is somehow causing network requests to fail when the app is in the background?

What might be the problem here, and is there any solution?

Comment: Go through this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57527501/error-fetch-when-app-is-put-in-background